# Prove $[ln(N)]^k \le cN$ for some positive constant c

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

How to go about proving there exist some constant $c$ which would make $[ln(N)]^k \le cN$ , where k is also a constant.

Comment: Does $\log^k (N)$ refer to $\left[\ln(N)\right]^k$ or does it refer to $\log_{k}(N)$?

Comment: $\log^k(N)$ refers to $[ln(N)]^k$. I have also updated the post.

Comment: If you're looking for asymptotic behaviour, I'd suggest showing this with a limit: by L'Hospital's rule and induction you can show that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\ln^k(N)}{N} = 0$ for nonnegative integers $k,$ and noninteger $k$ aren't a problem because $\ln^{\lceil k \rceil}(N) > \ln^k(N).$

Comment: Let $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{\left[\ln(x)\right]^k}{x}$.  It is routine to show that there exists a specific fixed real number $M$, which is a function of  the (presumably) fixed value of $k$ such that for all $x > M, ~f'(x) < 0.$

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @rtybase